# How to use sprite groups and kill sprite group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

code:

```
import pygame

def enemie():
    global speed_x
    ball.y += speed_x

    if ball.colliderect(player):
        groups.kill()


pygame.init()
running = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

speed_x = 10

ball = pygame.Rect(250, 0 ,20,20)
player = pygame.Rect(250, 450, 50, 50)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

Groups = pygame.sprite.Group()
Groups.add(ball)
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    enemie()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) #color

    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, [0, 0, 255], player)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, [255, 0, 0], ball)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

error:

```
TypeError: pygame.sprite.AbstractGroup.add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'pygame.Rect'
```

First of all, I have never seen such a huge error before. I am trying to create a game where you have a ball coming from above and when it touches your blue character, The red ball is deleted. I got everything good until I tried to remove the ball when touched. I used a sprite group so I could 'kill' the group. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot kill a sprite *Group*, but you can kill a *Sprite*. [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) removes a sprite from all groups. You just can a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects to a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). `ball` is just a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. Therefore it cannot be add to a *Group*.

---

Working example:

```py
import pygame

def enemie():
    global speed_x
    ball.rect.y += speed_x
    if ball.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
        player.kill()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# ball sprite
ball = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
ball.rect = pygame.Rect(250, 0, 20, 20)
ball.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(ball.image, (255, 0, 0), (10, 10), 10)
speed_x = 10

# player sprite
player = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
player.rect = pygame.Rect(250, 450, 50, 50)
player.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(player.image, (0, 0, 255), (25, 25), 25)

# group with all sprites
group = pygame.sprite.Group()
group.add(ball)
group.add(player)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    enemie()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) #color
    group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: how do you remove a rect from my screen then?